# Primefaces component not respond after the session expired

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a filter which checks the session. My filter:

```
public class FilterLogin implements Filter{

    FilterConfig fc;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        fc = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        if (session.getAttribute("loginMB") == null) {
            resp.sendRedirect("/home.xhtml");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>pl.ePrzychodnia.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/home.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

When the session is expired I should go to the site home.xhtml. But when the session is expired and I want click the navigation menu in the page, the component is not reacting to the click...
When I do not use Primefaces everything works correctly. When I use primefaces in my project I have this error. What could be the cause?

I try use a global exception handler but i have a little problem. I copy class from this site  http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/adding-global-exception-handling-using-jsf-2-x-exceptionhandler/

and edited in class CustomExceptionHandler:

```
try {

                //log error ?
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Critical Exception!", t);

                //redirect error page
                requestMap.put("exceptionMessage", t.getMessage());
                nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/home");
                fc.renderResponse();

                // remove the comment below if you want to report the error in a jsf error message
                //JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(t.getMessage());

            }
```

I change: `nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/error");` to `nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/home");`

But when session timeout i not reditect to home.xhtml page only go to the page when I clicked and i have a example error:

```
SEVERE: Critical Exception!
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/protected/admin/about.xhtml - View /protected/admin/about.xhtml could not be restored.
```

when i clicked reference to about page when my session expired. I see a incomplete about.xhtml page instead home.xhtml

Comment: are you getting any error messages? which primeface and JSF version ?

Comment: you could try primefaces [idleMonitor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/idlemonitorHome.jsf)

Comment: Post the xhtml portion on where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most possibly, you make an ajax call to the managed bean. That is why error navigation does not work in web xml. The error will be send to JavaScript callback `onerror` if the action is invoked as ajax request.

You can add a global exception handler to application if you want to handle errors on server side. [Adding global exception handling using JSF](http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/adding-global-exception-handling-using-jsf-2-x-exceptionhandler/) tutorial is a good one to follow.

Furthermore, you can use [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) feature of [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/)

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong. I'm just trying to understand your answer in case I run into a similar problem in the future. So please forgive me if I sound like I am. The `onerror` function is invoked when there's a problem with `ajax` request no ? How does this relate to navigation ? Can you please explain.

Comment: I use a first way global exception handlinb, but I have a little problem. I edited my first post.

Comment: Your question seems completely different from the first one now which makes my answer worthless. My answer is completely meaningless to further users who face the same problem. Please ask another question when your problem changes. @Orange91 and i am glad you solved.